# How to use protect one element in an array in openMP?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

For example:

```
int a[100];
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   a[i]=i;
}
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(a[0])
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{

    a[i]=a[i]+a[((i+1)%100)];

}
```

However, it compiles failure:

```
error: syntax error in omp clause
 #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(a[0])
                                        ^
```

Sorry for my previous description. I want the output to be : a[i]=a[i]+a[((i+1)%100)],for example, a[10]=a[10]+a[11],a[99]=a[99]+a[0]. However, when i becomes 99, a[99] should be a[99]=a[99]+a[0]. But when the thread executes a[99]=a[99]+a[0], the value of a[0] has been changed into a[0]=a[0]+a[1] by another paralleled thread(it has dependency). What should I do to  guarantee that each thread can use original value in a[i] to finish a[i]=a[i]+a[((i+1)%100)] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not guaranteed to get the correct result because it has a race condition.  One way to fix this is to do it out-of-place like this

```
void foo2(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b) {
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i] + a[((i + 1) % N)];
    }   
}
```

If you really want to do it in-place then it's a bit complicated

```
void foo3(int a[]) {    
    int n = N - 1;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int i;
        int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
        int nthread = omp_get_num_threads();
        int start = ithread*n / nthread;
        int finish = (ithread + 1)*n/ nthread;
        int tmp = a[finish];
        for (i = start; i < finish-1; i++) {
            a[i] += a[i + 1];
        }
        a[finish-1] += tmp;
    }
    a[n] += a[0];
}
```